# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x+n)=0$ for almost all $x$ if $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is Lebesgue-integrable

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x+n)=0$$ 
for almost all $x$ if $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is Lebesgue-integrable.

I attempted a proof by contrapositive, testing for the case that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x+n)=a>0$ for many $x$. Then I noticed that this is not sufficient, as it does not account for cases where the limit doesn't exist.

Now I don't see any alternative proof routes, as I'm mentally stuck on the last one. Also, I'm struggling with using the assumption $\lim f(x+n)$ as it takes the limit of discrete steps.

How could one attempt a proof?

Comment: Do you mean Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: @Bach edited, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem
$$\int_0^\infty |f(x)|\; dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 |f(n+x)| \; dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty |f(n+x)| \; dx $$
Thus for almost every $x \in [0,1]$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |f(n+x)|$ must converge, which implies $f(n+x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.